# Describe the automorphism group of the digraphs

Tags: graph-theory

Describe the automorphism group of the digraphs

[image]
Here is what I got so far

For $D_1$, because of the direction of $vw$, we can't do anything to the graph so $Aut(D_1)= I$

For $D_2$, we can flip the graph horizontally, so we have 2 automorphism, the identity and $\alpha=(u w)(c x)$

For $D_3$ I think the only think we can do is flip the graph over the arc $uy$, so we have 2 automorphisms the identity and $\alpha=(u x)$

I wonder if I missed or misunderstand anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two first are right, but for the third one you're missing some -- for example the automorphism that swaps $x$ and $y$ and leaves the other three nodes alone. In fact there are 6 automorphisms including the identity.

Note that a graph isomorphism doesn't need to be a *geometric* symmetry of the *drawing* of the graph -- it must just preserve the abstract which-nodes-have-edges-between-them relation.

Comment: oh, so I can swap $(x y)$, $(u v)$, $(v y)$ and $(u y)$ right?

Comment: @Diane: You can't swap $u$ with anything; it is the only node with in-degree 0, for example.

Comment: what do you mean by saying doesn't need to be geometric symmetry of the drawing? you mean I can rotate it? Because if I rotate it, the graph will look different?

Comment: @Diane: What I mean is that is is _immaterial_ how the graph _looks_. All that is necessary for an isomorphism is that $f(a)$ has an edge to $f(b)$ exactly when $a$ has an edge to $b$.

Comment: hum, then how can you get 6 automorphism? you can't touch $u$ and $w$, so only have $3$ vertices $x,y,v$ so I can map $x \to y$, $x \to v$ and $y \to v$. So the total is 4 automorphisms including the identity.

Comment: @Diane: How many ways are there to permute three elements? Note that "$x\mapsto y$" still leaves a choice as to what happens to $y$ and $v$. (Just because $x$ maps to $y$ doesn't mean $y$ must map back to $x$).

Comment: $3!=6$, you mean I'm allowed to have double mapping $x\to y \to v$ and $x \to v \to y$?

Comment: @Diane: Yes, if I understand you correctly, $\{x\mapsto y, y\mapsto v, v\mapsto x\}$ and $\{x\mapsto v,v\mapsto y,y\mapsto x\}$ are both valid automorphisms here.

Comment: yes, I should have wrote it as $(x y v)$ and $(x v y)$. Thank you very much for your help.